# ImportXML for Google Result says: "Could not fetch URL" in Google Sheet

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xml-parsing

For a school project, I'm trying to get the URL from the first item into a google search in a Google Sheet.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=23andMe", "//h3/a/@href")
```

**This Google Search is for the company 23andMe, and the operation should get their URL based on them being the first search result. Instead, it throws the error: "Could not fetch URL".**

There are multiple questions on similar topics on StackOverflow, but unfortunately the answers to this error are always a typo or other small mistake, but I have none that I can see.

**Why am I getting this error, and how can I get the URL for the first Google search result in my spreadsheet?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After waiting for several minutes, the program loaded again and no longer threw the error. It seems it was just a matter of time, and that this feature is simply buggy.